# Linq to sql making multiple calls in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

When I am updating a record with linq to sql my `DeleteLesson()` method is getting called multiple times.

My controller looks like this :

```
    public ActionResult  Delete(int id)
    {

        deleteLesson(id);

        return Content("<p style=color:red><strong>Deleted...</strong></p>");
    }

    public void deleteLesson(int id)
    {
        LLDataContext storeDB = new LLDataContext();

            lesson lesson = (from l in storeDB.lessons
                             where l.lessonID == id
                             select l).Single();

            lesson.statusID = DELETED;
            lesson.dateDeleted = DateTime.Now;
            lesson.deletedByUserID = getAppUserID();

            try
            {
                storeDB.SubmitChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

                storeDB.SubmitChanges();
            }
    }
```

And my view looks like this

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", 
                                     new { id = item.lessonID }, 
                                     new AjaxOptions {  

                                                       HttpMethod = "POST",
                                                       UpdateTargetId = @rowNumber.ToString()
                                     }
                                    )
```

Any Ideas?

EDIT

also if I use    `confirm = "Do you want to delete"`    in ajax options I will have to click okay three times.

Comment: This is really an MVC question and not related to LINQ as such if I understand correctly.

Comment: How do you know that the method is called many times? Did the debugger rise exceptions?

Comment: I know it is running multiple times for a couple reasons, if I set a break point it will hit deleteLesson() three times. It also throws an duplicate row exception.

Comment: based on your code, it shouldn't be calling that method multiple times for a single request.  Therefore, I expect the problem is on the client side (the browser).  Are you using AJAX?  Either way, check the Net tab in FireBug and make sure multiple HTTP requests are not being made.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting both a post and a get call to it?
try making

```
public ActionResult  Delete(int id)
```

into

```
[HttpPost()]
public ActionResult  Delete(int id)
```

specific to http post IMO.  Do you really want users browsing to /Lesson/Delete/5 and have it work anyway?  I'd think you only want this to handle from a postback where you're displaying the lesson they're going to delete.

Comment: top line got cut off, only using as a post it as  [HttpPost] above.